# How can I display greek letters in D3 svg.text objects?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am using D3 and want to add the greek letter delta.

This is in the  tag of my HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is where the problem lies:
'bars' is a variable that stores a selection of class '.bar' and appends 'g' to them.

```
var text = bars.append('text')
            .attr('class', 'delta')
            .text(function(d) {
                // Rounding to one decimal place
                var delta = Math.abs(d.benchmark - d.completes);
                return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "%";
            })
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('dy', '-0.25em')
            .attr('style', 'text-anchor: left; vertical-align: center')
            ;
```

In this particular line I get problems:

```
return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "%";
```

Things I have tried:

```
return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "%Δ"; //Displays ? instead of Δ
return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "%&Delta;" // Displays the string literal &Delta;
return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "%&#916;;" // Displays the string literal &#916;
```

Not really sure how to proceed. If it matters, the font is sans-serif

I am not very familiar with SVG text but all I want to do is write the greek letter delta.

Comment: Have you tried "\u0394" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "% \u0394";
```

Comment: I wrote a [more-detailed answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30920896/238884)

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions that will work (since HTML apparently does not):

- Encode the delta in Javascript, like this:

`return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "% \u0394";`

This is very reliable, but not very readable.

- Encode the delta in the file itself:

`return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "% Δ";`

This depends on proper handling of file-encoding all along (in your source-management, in your deployment, in your web server), so it is readable but fragile.

A compromise might be

```
const DeltaLetter = '\u0394';
...
return Math.round(delta * 10) / 10 + "% " + DeltaLetter;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **why not use unicode?**

   - UTF8 or UTF16
   - and encode the `Δ` as unicode 0394 hex
   - can use hex editor for that if you do not have tools able to do that
2. **can use INCSKAPE**

   - this is first valid link I found by google [Greek Alphabet in Inkscape](http://kestrel.nmt.edu/~raymond/software/howtos/greekscape.xhtml)

**[Edit2]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="1px" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0" >
<text x="5" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="16" fill="blue">
Greek alphabet test
<tspan x="5" dy="+20">
ΑΒΓΔ
</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

- in UTF-8 the `ΑΒΓΔ` is encoded as `CE,91,CE,92,CE,93,CE,94` in hex view
- in UTF-16 the `ΑΒΓΔ` is encoded as `91,03,92,03,93,03,94,03` in hex view
- do not forget that in UTF-16 each char is a 16 bit (2 bytes) !!!
- in UTF-8 all except the Greek letters is 1 Byte/character
- and the Greek characters itself are 2 Bytes/char

Comment: @Malvolio (+1) I forget that This page convert the text to its own unicode formatting. So I changed the example added hex view of UTF-8 and UTF-16 (had finally got working it in the UTF-8 also)